# JPA: Restriction in ManyToMany relations

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities: User and Event. Each user has a list of events that he pay attention to.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "login", length = 64)
    protected String login;

    @ManyToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_events",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "login") },
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "event_id") })
    protected List<Event> events;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long eventId;
}
```

But when a user pay attention to an event, then I can't delete that event from the database. It seems there is some restriction set by the JPA. Could anyone tell me how to fix that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th restriction is not set by JPA. It's in your database: the `event_id` join column in the join table is a foreign key to the ID of the event. You may not remove the event because some user is still referencing it.

If you want to delete the event, and also delete all the references from users to the event, then you must search for all the users referencing the event, remove the event from their list, and then delete the event.

```
String jpql = "select u from User u inner join u.events e where e.id = :eventId;
// execute the query
for (User u : users) {
    u.removeEvent(eventToDelete);
}
em.remove(eventToDelete);
```

Comment: Thank you and is this the only way to do this? Can I add some annotation so that when I delete an event then all the reference from users to that event will be deleted?

Comment: Except by using native SQL, I think this is the only way to go.